# Connecting to a database on a different network via VPN through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, perl, server-side, vpn

We currently have a process where a user uses Cisco VPN client to establish a secure tunnel to a remote server. They, then, remote desktop into a machine on the remote network. While on the remote machine, they fire up SQL Server 2008 Enterprise manager, run a query that produces a CSV file. The file is then manually transferred back to their local machine.

This process only needs to happen once a month to pull this CSV (report) from our remote machines.

The transport is IPSec/UDP.

I am having trouble finding any kind of help being able to do this through a script. Is this possible? If not through PHP, maybe through perl or any server side script?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is a machine you control (sounds like it?) why not do the opposite, set up a job on the SQL Server and let it push somewhere where you can access it. Setting up a tunnel using OpenSwan and then a simple PHP snippet to access the database is probably fully possible but kind of out of scope of this answer right now.

Comment: @hank Yes, we do control this machine, but not the network it sits on. That is a good idea, and I hadn't thought of pushing the data to me, instead of pulling it. I'd like to hear more of this OpenSwan. I'll do some reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl is able to do this.

Try too break this problem to two pieces:

1) Generate a CSV file.
2) Move this CSV file out.

**Part1:**

You could usee Perl to connect to SQL server, run a query and generate a CSV file.

Connect using ODBC and DBI: [How do I connect with Perl to SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905624/how-do-i-connect-with-perl-to-sql-server)

Use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to generate a valid CSV file.

**Part2:**

2.1: You could setup a simple (https) webserver to serve only this CSV file. IF it is needed you could encrypt this file before sending out.

You could use Putty to setup SSH Tunel to protect the transmission even further: http://www.planetb.ca/2010/08/how-to-create-an-ssh-tunnel-with-putty-and-stay-anonymous-on-a-network/

With this it willl be easy: http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Server::Brick

```
use HTTP::Daemon::SSL;

my $server = HTTP::Server::Brick->new(
      port => 8889,
      daemon_class => 'HTTP::Daemon::SSL',
      directory_indexing => 1,
      daemon_args  => [
         SSL_key_file  => 'my_ssl_key.pem',
         SSL_cert_file => 'my_ssl_cert.pem',
      ],
    );
$server->mount( '/csvfile' => {
    path => 'C:/path/to/your/csv/file',
    wildcard => 1,
}); 
# start accepting requests (won't return unless/until process
# receives a HUP signal)
$server->start;
```

2.2: You could setup ssh server on your machine and use scp(.exe from Putty) to copy the files.

https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows